# Creating function which generates random number between two arguments C

Tags: c

How can i create function in C , which would generate random number }(type double) between set arguments? In lot of languagues its simply just

```
function randomnumber(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

but i fail to find any good solution for type double in c.

Comment: ... you're using `floor` so you really want a random *integer*?

Comment: indeed , i just noticed , thanks for pointing out

Comment: `function`...? :) return type? type of arguments?

Comment: @ameyCU Proposed duplicate deals with `float`, yet the post request `double`.  That extra precision/range poses additional concerns that a good answer would provide.

Comment: trolkura  what type of distribution do you want: linear between `max` and `min`?  It is easier to not include one of the limits so like `[min...max)` rather than `[min... max]`.  Do you want to be able to generate every `double` between `min` and `max` or just most of them sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods.  Answer 1 above is ok for min, max as doubles.  The important thing to remember for `rand()` is that it returns a random integer between `0` and `RAND_MAX` inclusive.  `RAND_MAX` is a least `2^15`, but on most systems `2^31`.  If min and max are integers and their difference is less than `RAND_MAX` then a very easy method is:

```
delta = max - min;
r  = rand() % delta + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* rand(), srand(), RAND_MAX */

double randd(double min, double max) {
    int r = rand();
    double delta = max - min; /* assume max > min */
    double tmp = r / (RAND_MAX + 1.0); /* generate up to but excluding max */
    return tmp * delta + min;
}
```

Comment: See it running: http://ideone.com/EOGwIJ

Comment: OP was not very specific on the goals, yet this answer will likely not generate every `double` between `min` and `max`.

Comment: @chux Depending on `min` and `max` this answer, with its bias, can generate every `double` between those values .... and repeat some of the answers to boot (think 52 bits for the mantissa and 63 bits for the PRNG).

Comment: Rare machines have a `int` of 63+ bits - the return type of `rand()` - more likely to be 32-bit (or even 16) and so insufficient to generate all the range of `double` with many `min`, `max`.  Had this answers referenced a 63 bit PRNG or express how to compensate for insufficient `RAND_MAX` range, I would have not commented so.